# discord.py 1vs1 game - accept invite function

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a 1vs1 game that sends invite to user and awaits for accept. Here is my code:

```
global hasRun
hasRun = False
@client.command()
async def accept(ctx):
    global hasRun
    hasRun = True

@client.command() 
async def fight(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('sending invite to user')
    await user.send('press `/accept` to start the game')
    await ctx.send('waiting for accept..')
    global hasRun
    if hasRun == True:
      await ctx.send("game started")
```

Code doesnt drop any error but it just doesnt work. Any idea where the fault lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting to see if hasRun been true. As soon as you send `Waiting for accept...` it checks if hasRun is true or not, which is likely False.

Instead of using a separate command and a global variable you can use [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

The check function will check if the user you asked for sends a message to accept the game. You should also include a timeout.

```py
import asyncio # Required for timeout

# ...

@client.command() 
async def fight(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('sending invite to user')
    await user.send('press `accept` to start the game')
    await ctx.send('waiting for accept..')
    def check(message):
        return message.author == user and message.content in ('accept', '/accept')
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("User didn't accept game in time")
    # Code can go here
```

Comment: thanks a lot! :)